# Simplify a chain of computations

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, window-functions

I would like to make a query similar to this:

```
SELECT
  time,
  close - LAG(close) OVER (ORDER BY time) AS "diff"
  CASE WHEN diff > 0 THEN diff ELSE 0 END AS gain,
  CASE WHEN diff < 0 THEN diff ELSE 0 END AS loss,
  AVG(gain) OVER (ORDER BY time ROWS 40 PRECEDING) as avg_gain,
  AVG(loss) OVER (ORDER BY time ROWS 40 PRECEDING) AS avg_loss
  avg_gain / avg_loss AS rs,
  100 - (100 / NULLIF(1+rst.rs, 0)) as rsi
FROM candles_5min
WHERE symbol = 'AAPL';
```

But from what I can tell, SQL doesn't allow references to columns created within the same `SELECT`. So I have to do something like:

```
SELECT rst.time, 100 - (100 / NULLIF((1+rst.rs), 0)) as rsi
FROM (SELECT
avgs.time,
avgs.avg_gain / NULLIF(avgs.avg_loss, 0) AS rs
FROM (SELECT glt.time, AVG(glt.gain) OVER (ORDER BY time ROWS 40 PRECEDING) as avg_gain,
    AVG(glt.loss) OVER (ORDER BY time ROWS 40 PRECEDING) AS avg_loss
FROM (SELECT
    dt.time,
    CASE WHEN dt.diff > 0 THEN dt.diff ELSE 0 END AS gain,
    CASE WHEN diff < 0 THEN diff ELSE 0 END AS loss
    FROM (SELECT
    time,
    close - LAG(close) OVER (ORDER BY time) AS "diff"
    FROM candles_5min
    WHERE symbol = 'AAPL') AS dt) AS glt) AS avgs) AS rst
```

Is there any way to simplify a query like this one? I'm using PostgreSQL.

Comment: Unfortunately that's just what SQL is like :( - so while you can't "simplify" the query much, you could reformulate it using named CTEs instead of using nested-queries, which is much easier to read as the queries become top-level and can also be reused if necessary - instead of being deeply-nested.

Comment: It would be instrumental to add a minimal test case with table definition and sample values to assist with testing. And always disclose your version of Postgres. `SELECT version();` helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a window function based on another window function, which cannot be nested in the same `SELECT` list. So you need a minimum of two query levels. But that minimum seems feasible:

```sql
SELECT time
     , 100 - (100 / NULLIF((1 + AVG(GREATEST(diff, 0)) OVER w
                          / NULLIF(AVG(LEAST(diff, 0)) OVER w, 0)), 0)) AS rsi
FROM  (
   SELECT time
        , close - LAG(close) OVER (ORDER BY time) AS diff
   FROM   candles_5min
   WHERE  symbol = 'AAPL'
   ) dt
WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY time ROWS 40 PRECEDING);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/PGReGwM0)

You can replace the lengthy `CASE` expressions with dedicated (100 % equivalent) [`GREATEST()` and `LEAST()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-GREATEST-LEAST).

You can use a [`WINDOW` clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-WINDOW) to avoid spelling out the same frame for multiple window functions in the same `SELECT` list. Results in the same query plan, so no effect on performance. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-WINDOW)

> ... the `WINDOW` clause saves typing when the same window definition is needed for more than one window function.

Overall, I expect my rewrite to be only slightly faster. But you asked for a simplified query, not performance, so that's ok.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for - I wasn't aware of the difference between window functions and normal functions (now I gotta figure out aggregates...). Your query is much more readable. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite it with ctes instead of subqueries, that woul keep it better readable and you cann better debug it.

But you can do

```
SELECT
  time,
  close - LAG(close) OVER (ORDER BY time) AS "diff",
  CASE WHEN close - LAG(close) OVER (ORDER BY time)  > 0 THEN close - LAG(close) OVER (ORDER BY time) ELSE 0 END AS gain,
  CASE WHEN close - LAG(close) OVER (ORDER BY time)  < 0 THEN close - LAG(close) OVER (ORDER BY time) ELSE 0 END AS loss,
  AVG(CASE WHEN close - LAG(close) OVER (ORDER BY time)  > 0 THEN close - LAG(close) OVER (ORDER BY time) ELSE 0 END ) OVER (ORDER BY time ROWS 40 PRECEDING) as avg_gain,
  AVG(CASE WHEN close - LAG(close) OVER (ORDER BY time)  < 0 THEN close - LAG(close) OVER (ORDER BY time) ELSE 0 END) OVER (ORDER BY time ROWS 40 PRECEDING) AS avg_loss,
  AVG(CASE WHEN close - LAG(close) OVER (ORDER BY time)  > 0 THEN close - LAG(close) OVER (ORDER BY time) ELSE 0 END ) OVER (ORDER BY time ROWS 40 PRECEDING) 
  / AVG(CASE WHEN close - LAG(close) OVER (ORDER BY time)  < 0 THEN close - LAG(close) OVER (ORDER BY time) ELSE 0 END) OVER (ORDER BY time ROWS 40 PRECEDING) AS rs,
  100 - (100 / NULLIF(1+
  (AVG(CASE WHEN close - LAG(close) OVER (ORDER BY time)  > 0 THEN close - LAG(close) OVER (ORDER BY time) ELSE 0 END ) OVER (ORDER BY time ROWS 40 PRECEDING) 
  / AVG(CASE WHEN close - LAG(close) OVER (ORDER BY time)  < 0 THEN close - LAG(close) OVER (ORDER BY time) ELSE 0 END) OVER (ORDER BY time ROWS 40 PRECEDING)), 0)) as rsi
FROM candles_5min
WHERE symbol = 'AAPL';
```

you should benchmark it

Comment: yes you are iright i corrected it thx